# VIM Issue using <cword> in a mapping

Tags: java, vim, configuration, mapping

I'm trying to add a nifty mapping to `vim` that uses `command-t`. The idea is that i can have the cursor over a class name, hit `<leader>f`, and the relevant `.java` file for that class will be immediately opened in a new buffer (i have `hidden` set to `on`).

My `.vimrc` contains

```
map <leader>f :CommandT<cr>=expand("<cword>")<tab><cr>
```

Which works perfectly, except that the cursor word isn't expanded, and I end up searching for `=expand("<cword>")`, rather than the cursor word itself.

I have also tried simply;

```
map <leader>f :CommandT<cr><cword><tab><cr>
```

To much the same effect (`<cword>` is pasted and searched for). The good news is if I manually do;

```
map <leader>f :CommandT<cr>MyClassName<tab><cr>
```

it works perfectly, so at least the theory is right.

Comment: What is the added benefit of using Command-T? Why not simply `:e <C-r><C-w><Tab>`?

Comment: @romainl partly because it's something I find myself doing so often that I wanted to reduce it to just one key combination, partly just to see if I could :)

Comment: Yes we all do that very often, that's why `<C-]>` exists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [ctags](http://ctags.sourceforge.net/), that's what it's made for.

1. Install ctags.
2. Index your project:

   ```
   :!ctags -R .
   ```
3. Make sure Vim finds the correct `tags` file (the index of your project) wherever you are in your project:

   ```
   set tags=./tags,tags:$HOME
   ```
4. Place your cursor on a method or class name and hit the following shortcut to jump to the definition:

   ```
   <C-]>
   ```

   Or this one to open a new window:

   ```
   <C-w>]
   ```

   And this one to jump back:

   ```
   <C-t>
   ```

   Or this one to show the signature in a small preview window:

   ```
   <C-w>}
   ```

See `:help tags` for more.

Comment: This is a really great plugin, thanks for pointing it out to me.

Comment: ctags is not a plugin: it's an independent program with which Vim interacts quite well. See also cscope, if you are curious.

Answer (score 4):

You have to use feedkeys:

```
nnoremap \f :<C-u>execute'CommandT'<Bar>call feedkeys(expand('<cword>')."\t\<LT>CR>",'t')<CR>
```

. Some other note: don’t use `map` unless you really need remapping (hence `nore`, I see no need in this here) and all its modes (normal, operator-pending and visual) (hence leading `n`).

`\t` inside double-quoted string is a shorthand for `\<LT>Tab>` or `<C-v><Tab>` (inside mapping you have to use one of these to either insert literal `\<Tab>` into string (first) or literal tab (second)).

Comment: Thanks for this answer, it has pointed me in some new directions for the future. Ctags seems to be a better solution for this particular problem though.